# Not able to reset input field in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade

I need to reset the input field when user clicks on the rest button, I have other content on the page which is getting cleared except input field, I'm not sure if this is happening because I'm using old values after post request.

```
 <input type="text" name="app_number" class="form-control" onreset="this.value=''" value="{!! Request::input('app_number') !!}" id="app_number" placeholder="Application Number" required>
```

JS for reset button:

```
document.getElementById("appForm").onreset = function() {
   document.getElementById("app_number").value = "";
  };
```

Reset Button:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="reset-button" type="reset">Reset</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `type="reset"` for your button:

```
<button type="reset">Cancel</button>
```

Comment: I'm already using `<button class="btn btn-primary" id="reset-button" type="reset">Reset</button>`

Comment: is the input field in a form?

Comment: yeah its in a form name `appForm`

Comment: Then my guess is `Request::input('app_number')` always has a value. https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G4K2WX7BQT56

Comment: yeah thats what i thought too, but I need old value there, I tried `old('app_number')` but its not working either

Comment: You may need to add some clarity to your question.

Answer (score 0):

try using reset():
document.getElementById("app_number").reset();

Comment: try : document.getElementById("app_number").reset();

Answer (score 0):

In this case you must use JQuery Lib. Basic you need to set ID for this element. And in jquery you listen click on this Element.

```
$('#app_number').on('change', function () {
   // enter code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your reset button :

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="reset-button" onclick="myFunction()">Reset</button>
```

In js:

```
function myFunction(){
   document.getElementById("app_number").value = "";
}
```

Comment: The thing is I'm not using JQuery, I need vanilla JS

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use in js like:

```
$(document).on('click', '#YourOnclickButtonID', function(){
    var $alertas = $('#YourFormID');
    $alertas.validate().resetForm();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So answering my own question, any feedback would be appreciated but this is working.

It turns out that no matter what `value="{!! Request::input('app_number') !!}"` will always have value as this code gets executed on the server side and unless you make another `post` request you can not change the value and by using only vanilla JS and without post request this cannot be done.

So, instead of getting values from `Request` why not just takes the values from user input and save it to local storage and then just grab it and inject into the input field.

I added `onkeyup` event ion to the input field

```
<input type="text" name="app_number" class="form-control" onkeyup='saveValue(this);' id="app_number" placeholder="Application Number" required>
```

and JS to store and retrieve input

```
document.getElementById("app_number").value = getSavedValue("app_number"); // set the value to this input

function saveValue(e) {
  var id = e.id; // get the sender's id to save it .
  var val = e.value; // get the value.
  localStorage.setItem(id, val); // Every time user writing something, the localStorage's value will override .
}

//get the saved value function - return the value of "v" from localStorage.
function getSavedValue(v) {
  if (!localStorage.getItem(v)) {
      return ""; // You can change this to your defualt value.
  }
  return localStorage.getItem(v);
}
```

and then reset the form as usual

```
document.getElementById("appForm").onreset = function() {
document.getElementById("app_number").value = '';
};
```